# How to get rid of points in legends with ggnewscale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a plot made with ggplot where the legends adds extra black points to all the other legends (see image).

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)
set.seed(12345)
brks = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1)
fd = expand.grid(x = seq(6,16, length.out = 100), 
                 y = seq(6,18, length.out = 100))
fd$z = sample(x = seq(0,1, length.out = 100), size = nrow(fd), replace = T)
df.t = data.frame(s = LETTERS[1:5], l = c(11,12,8,15,14), d = c(13,10,7,16,8))
mypal = data.frame(A = "black", B = "red",C = "blue", D = "green", E = "yellow")
summmmmmmm = expand.grid(s = LETTERS[1:5], 
                         yr = 1995:2012)
summmmmmmm$yr = as.factor(summmmmmmm$yr)
summmmmmmm$l = NA
summmmmmmm$d = NA
summmmmmmm[summmmmmmm$s == "A","l"] = rnorm(n = 18, mean = 11, sd = .5)
summmmmmmm[summmmmmmm$s == "B","l"] = rnorm(n = 18, mean = 12, sd = .5)
summmmmmmm[summmmmmmm$s == "C","l"] = rnorm(n = 18, mean = 8, sd = .5)
summmmmmmm[summmmmmmm$s == "D","l"] = rnorm(n = 18, mean = 15, sd = .5)
summmmmmmm[summmmmmmm$s == "E","l"] = rnorm(n = 18, mean = 14, sd = .5)
summmmmmmm[summmmmmmm$s == "A","d"] = rnorm(n = 18, mean = 13, sd = .5)
summmmmmmm[summmmmmmm$s == "B","d"] = rnorm(n = 18, mean = 10, sd = .5)
summmmmmmm[summmmmmmm$s == "C","d"] = rnorm(n = 18, mean = 8, sd = .5)
summmmmmmm[summmmmmmm$s == "D","d"] = rnorm(n = 18, mean = 16, sd = .5)
summmmmmmm[summmmmmmm$s == "E","d"] = rnorm(n = 18, mean = 9, sd = .5)
ggplot(data = fd, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) + 
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = brks)+
  geom_point(data = df.t, 
             mapping = aes(x = l, y = d, color = s), inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values =  alpha(hcl.colors(100, "YlOrRd", rev = TRUE, alpha = 1), .99))+
  scale_color_manual(values = alpha(mypal,1), 
                     name = "obj")+
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(data = summmmmmmm, 
             mapping = aes(x = l, y = d, 
                           color = yr, group = s), 
             shape = 19, 
             inherit.aes = FALSE, 
             show.legend = TRUE) + 
  geom_path(data = summmmmmmm[order(summmmmmmm$yr),], 
            mapping = aes(x = l, y = d, color = yr, 
                          group = as.factor(s)), inherit.aes = FALSE, 
            show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_viridis_d(name = "time")
```

I'd like to get rid of those extra points. Also, I like the 'time' legend to be in 2 columns, but not the other legends. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `guide = guide_legend(ncol = 2)` in your viridis scale to get two columns.

You can set `show.legend = c(colour = TRUE, fill = FALSE)` in the second point layer, to specifically show the legend in colour scales but not in fill scales.

See example below (where I've renamed `summmmmmmm` to `df` for my own sanity)

```r
ggplot(data = fd, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) + 
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = brks)+
  geom_point(
    data = df.t, 
    mapping = aes(x = l, y = d, color = s), inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 5
  ) + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values =  alpha(hcl.colors(100, "YlOrRd", rev = TRUE, alpha = 1), .99)
  )+
  scale_color_manual(values = alpha(mypal,1), name = "obj")+
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(
    data = df, 
    mapping = aes(x = l, y = d, color = yr, group = s), 
    shape = 19, inherit.aes = FALSE, 
    show.legend = c(colour = TRUE, fill = FALSE)
  ) + 
  geom_path(
    data = df[order(df$yr),], 
    mapping = aes(x = l, y = d, color = yr, group = as.factor(s)), 
    inherit.aes = FALSE, show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_color_viridis_d(name = "time", guide = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I didn't know we could do that. This is much better. Do you have a reference to what could be put inside `show.legend`?

Comment: It's documented in `?layer` and the bit reads: "It can also be a named logical vector to finely select the aesthetics to display.".

Comment: OK thanks! I'm also trying to find a way to control the grey background of the points individually for each legend (e.g., remove the grey background for 'time' and 'obj' but not 'level'). I just saw there is a `draw_key_glyph` But this is not the background but the actual pictogram inside the legend.

Comment: As far as I know, this is a global theme setting called `legend.theme`, but it applies to all legends equally. I don't think there is a straightforward solution for that.